# comparing two files and display matched results

Tags: perl

I've got the following problem to solve...I have two files containing the following information:

a.txt

```
alan, 23, alan@yahoo.com
albert, 27, albert@yahoo.com
```

b.txt

```
alan:173:analyst
victor:149:director
albert:171:clerk
coste:27:driver
```

I need to extract name(zero field) from every line of both files, compare them and if they match, print age and occupation information.
Thus, my output should be:

```
alan, 23, analyst
albert, 27, clerk
```

What I have got so far, and it's not working:

```
open F2, 'a.txt' or die $!;
@interesting_lines = <F2>;

foreach $line (@interesting_lines ) {
    @string = split(', ', $line);
    print "$string[0]\n";
}
close F2;

open F1, 'b.txt' or die $!;
while (defined(my $line = <F1>)) {
    @string2 = split(':', $line);
    print $string2[0];
    print "$.:\t$string2[0]" if grep {$string2[0] eq $_} $string[0] ;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how can I implement my requirements? Thanks...
Ps, bith files might have more lines than I posted, but file b.txt will always have every name that file a.tx has, plus extra lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open my $F2, '<', 'a.txt' or die $!;
chomp(my @interesting_lines = <$F2>);
close $F2;

my %dic;
foreach my $line (@interesting_lines) {
  my ($name, @arr) = split(/, /, $line);
  $dic{$name} = \@arr;
}

open my $F1, '<', 'b.txt' or die $!;

while (my $line = <$F1>) {
  chomp($line);
  my ($name, $pos) = ( split(/:/, $line) )[0, 2];

  my $arr = $dic{$name} or next;
  printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", $name, $arr->[0], $pos, $arr->[1]);
}
close $F1;
```

Comment: mpapec, thanks a lot. yes, the updated version works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @WisdomSeeker you accept answer by clicking checkbox on the left side of the answer

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that. I only started using this forum recently, lol.